# My featured image is not showing when I try to put as background image

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a properties table, which stores an image.
If I show the image inside the image attribute I can see it.

```
<img src="{{{{$property->featured_image}}}}">
```

This is how I return the image in my model

```
public function getFeaturedImageAttribute($path) {
  if ( $path ) {
    return $this->uploads.$path;
  }
}
```

The images is in public directory, in a folder called images.

How can I show this same image as background image?

I tried this:

```
<div id="thumbnail" style="background: url(https://ibin.co/4C4hfps5SKiw.jpg); ">
```

But when I visit the page I do not see the image and when I inspect the console nothing shows either.

Comment: do it this way <div id="thumbnail" style="background: {{url("the_path_of_image")}} ">

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your div is empty and this is reason. Try add border then you can see size of DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `background` css property isnt overrided ? Did u try with `background-image` ?

Works for me